# Building carousel with 3 slides per grid using js array for loop

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-carousel

Here's what's happening  below:
Overally I'm iterating over two arrays. One main array; second is sub array of main array.

My subarray is items.image_urls

```
let urls = items.image_urls.slice();
let result = [] 
var first_index = 0
var html  = `<div id="myCarousel`+current_index+`" class="carousel slide">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">` #I start by defining my carousel here.


while (urls.length > 0) result.push(urls.splice(0, 3));
   result.forEach(function(results){
      first_index++
      if (first_index == 1){
        html += `<div class="item active"><div class="row">`#Here I set the first item to be active; I'm not doing this part right.
      }else{
        html += `<div class="item"><div class="row">` 
      }
      ## Here I loop furthur into my splices; to get the element.


      var image_collection = '' # I set an empty var where eventually I want to append all my images here for my column.
      results.forEach(function(results){
           #Here is where I define my columns; in this case I want 3 columns generated here. 


           #I see rows as slides and columns as items in those rows.


           #As of now I'm doing this:


           image_collection+= `<div style='margin-left:12%;' onclick = "setMainImage('`+results+`')" style="display:inline-block;max-width:100%; width:20%;max-height: 20%;" class="col-sm-2"><img  style=" border-radius: 8px; height:100px;" src="`+results+`"  class="img-responsive" alt="test1">
           </div>`

      })
       html += image_collection ## I then add html and image collection together.


   ## here i close up my carousel
    html+= `</div>
                <a style="color:blue; font-size:3.0vw;" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel`+current_index+`" data-slide="prev"> ‹
                </a>

                <a style="color:blue; font-size:3.0vw;" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel`+current_index+`" data-interval="false"  data-slide="next">›
                </a>
            </div>`     

   })
```

ISSUE:
1. Doing following; I seem to only get data for item active; there is no other items. Being said `html +=` isn't really being appended.[I get

How can I successfully create a bootstrap carousel with 3 items per slides.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not using template literal properly.

Please check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to understand more about it and take advantages of it to make your code cleaner.

For your question,

```
result.push(urls.splice(0, 3));
```

is your problem.

You are pushing into first index of the array so you are suppose to loop through `result[0]` instead of `result` array instead like following.

```
result[0].forEach(function(results) {
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xufswugh/)